# Doctrine OneToMany relationship error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, many-to-one

I am trying to set up some ManyToOne/OneToMany relationships on objects in my database using Doctrine (2.2.3+) via Symfony2 (2.3.0) and am getting a strange error.  Here are the relevant parts of the objects (many attributes to one product):

```
/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    ...

    /**
     *
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductAttributes", mappedBy="product")
     */
    protected $product_attributes;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->product_attributes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/**
 * ProductAttributes
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_attributes")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProductAttributes
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pa_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $pa_id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $product_id;

    ...

    /**
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="product_attributes")
     * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;
}
```

When I run the

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities BundleName
```

command I get the following error:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                                                                            
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@OneToMany" in property LVMount\LVMBundle\Entity\Product::$product_attributes was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

I have looked through the Doctrine docs and don't see any reference to a "use" statement for the ManyToOne/OneToMany pairings.  What is going on?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your annotations' syntax aren't complete.

You can see the proper syntax for any doctrine annotation below.

```
/**
 * @ORM\********
 */
```

So, in your case it should look like the following.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductAttributes", mappedBy="product")
 */
```

You will also want to fix the annotations in the `ProductAttributes` entity.